# Receiving String from Raspberry pi over Bluetooth

Tags: java, android, python, bluetooth

I am developing an android app to receive string serially from raspberry pi 2 over Bluetooth.

the code is working well but only begintoListentoData is not working ..

```
package com.first.majazen.appfinal;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;
import android.os.Handler;


public class Recieve extends Activity {
    private static String mystuff;
    private static final String TAG = mystuff;
    BluetoothSocket mmSocket = null;
    BluetoothDevice mmDevice = null;
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    DataInputStream mmInputStream;
    Thread workerThread;
    byte[] readBuffer;
    int readBufferPosition;
    volatile  boolean stopWorker;
    EditText text;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recieve);

        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.text);
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBluetooth = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBluetooth, 0);
            Log.i("myStuff", "Bluetooth Enabled");
        } else {
            Log.i("myStuff", "Bluetooth Already Enabled");
        }
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                if (device.getName().equals("RNBT-E965")) {
                    mmDevice = device;
                    Log.i("myStuff", "Device equals " + device.getName());
                    try {
                        openBT();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.i("myStuff", "BT not opened");
                    }
                }}
        }




    }

    public void openBT()throws IOException {


        UUID uuid = mmDevice.getUuids()[0].getUuid(); //if you don't know the UUID of the bluetooth device service, you can get it like this from android cache
        Log.d(TAG, "UUID: " + uuid.toString());
        mmSocket = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
        mmSocket.connect();
        Log.i("myStuff", "Connected OK!");
        mmInputStream = new DataInputStream(mmSocket.getInputStream());
        beginListenForData()
    }


    public void BackActivity(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


   public void beginListenForData() {
      final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final byte delimiter = 10;

       stopWorker = false;
        readBufferPosition =0;
        readBuffer = new byte[1024];
        workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()&& !stopWorker){
                    try{
                        text.setText("manal");

                        int bytesAvailable = mmInputStream.available();
                        if(bytesAvailable >0){
                            byte[] packetBytes =new byte[bytesAvailable];
                            mmInputStream.read(packetBytes);
                            for (int i=0; i<bytesAvailable; i++){
                                byte b = packetBytes[i];
                                if (b== delimiter){
                                    byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
                                    System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0, encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);
                                    final String data = new String(encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");
                                    readBufferPosition = 0;
                                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                        public void run(){
                                            text.setText(data);

                                            Log.i("myStuff", "Received");

                                        }
                                    });
                                } else {
                                    readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }catch (IOException ex){
                        stopWorker = true;
                        Log.i("myStuff", "not Received");

                    }
            }
        }
        }); workerThread.start();
    }




}
```

the python code is here:

```
from time import sleep
import serial
ser = serial.Serial(port='/dev/serial0', boudrate=115200)

while True:
  ser.write("project ")
```

here is the logcat I have

please help me to solve this problem!

```
04-24 15:52:41.591 3991-6131/com.first.majazen.appfinal E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-65679
                                                                          Process: com.first.majazen.appfinal, PID: 3991
                                                                          android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:8251)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1307)
                                                                              at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:20148)
                                                                              at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:20148)
                                                                              at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:20148)
                                                                              at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:20148)
                                                                              at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:20148)
                                                                              at android.widget.TextView.checkForResize(TextView.java:8357)
                                                                              at android.widget.TextView.spanChange(TextView.java:9404)
                                                                              at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onSpanAdded(TextView.java:12067)
                                                                              at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendSpanAdded(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1057)
                                                                              at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:763)
                                                                              at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:662)
                                                                              at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:125)
                                                                              at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:134)
                                                                              at android.text.method.ArrowKeyMovementMethod.initialize(ArrowKeyMovementMethod.java:325)
                                                                              at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4976)
                                                                              at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4834)
                                                                              at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:117)
                                                                              at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4809)
                                                                              at com.first.majazen.appfinal.Recieve$1.run(Recieve.java:99)
                                                                              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score 0):

Line 99, replace

```
    text.setText(data);
```

By

```
    Recieve.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            text.setText(data);
        }
    });
```

As stated in the error Log, you are trying to modify the GUI from another thread than the GUI thread. That is forbidden.
Also, try to encapsulate this snippet into another method for better readability.

Comment: it generates another error on line 126 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-67716   Process: com.first.majazen.appfinal, PID: 8616   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1024; index=1024      at com.first.majazen.appfinal.Recieve$1.run(Recieve.java:126)                             line 126 :      readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;

Comment: either change your buffer size of :          if( bytesAvailable >0 && readBufferPosition < 1024 )

Comment: still the error of readBuffer: it gives me this error :                                                04-24 19:31:40.331 2646-3729/com.first.majazen.appfinal E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-76971
Process: com.first.majazen.appfinal, PID: 2646
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1024; index=1024
 at com.first.majazen.appfinal.Recieve$1.run(Recieve.java:131)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Comment: You are trying to write outside your buffer. It's size is limited to 1024 bytes by yourself. 
Also, you're testing the buffer availability and trying to read it in two different conditions.

Try Logging the content of bytesAvailable. It should help you understand the problem.

Also, please use proper indentation and spacing. Your code is almost unreadable.

Comment: it gave me another problem.. "threads took ms" please help :(

Comment: Can you please give more context and log? Only "threads took ms" doesn't really help :)